# Other .aar library not included in .aar library after build

Tags: android-studio, android-library, aar

I have a library project A, which contains a custom library B in aar format, which is hosted on a Maven Server.

If I build A now and export it as an aar, B is not included in the file, whereas several jar libs are included.

I´ve checked the .iml file of my module and found the following lines:

```
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.libs/libraryb/0.0.1/jars" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/jars" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/22.2.1/jars" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads/7.8.0/jars" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-analytics/7.8.0/jars" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-appindexing/7.8.0/jars" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-base/7.8.0/jars" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-plus/7.8.0/jars" />
```

Those contents seem to be excluded completely.

**Is it possible to have the aar included in any way or does it only work with jar files?**

Comment: were you able to resolve this ?  I am in same boat :(

Comment: sadly I think it´s not possible and wanted by default

Comment: I hope that's not the case, or it'll make my project a tad more complicated. However, since I've run into the same issue, it does indeed look like an imported .aar library doesn't get included in any build outputs.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo This helps if you wrap a submodule around your aar (without maven) https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar